# Can't change Path of cmd in Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

On cmd i use this command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Test
```

It Worked!

But, if i use this code in a python file, it not work!

```
import os
os.system('set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Test')
```

I tried this code too:

```
import os
path = 'C:\Test'
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path
```

It not work!

But this code work very well (i need restart cmd to see change):

```
# Delete a part of PATH
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['path'][:414]
```

So, my questions is:

- Why i can't change PATH in python like that?
- How to change it in python?

Comment: `os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'][...]` doesn't work either, for me

Comment: You can exit cmd, and reopen it

Comment: I test on windows, u use linux?

Comment: No, Windows 7, 64-bit, python 3.3. Ah I see the python 2.7 tag.. will try that. Still, the result is nothing changed (although I try to delete the start of the string, not the end)

Comment: Oh, i think different is "I use python 2.7", u can try run as adminitrator cmd

Comment: Changing Python's copy of `PATH` will only affect child processes started by Python, i.e. via `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: @eryksun So, can you tell me what is right way to change PATH in python?

Comment: `setx.exe` modifies the value in the registry and then broadcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to top-level windows. Explorer handles this message by reloading its environment from the registry. Subsequently spawned child processes of Explorer will inherit the new environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

os.system('setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Test" /M')

Comment: I saw :` SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.` but it still not work :(

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear!