# How to set Environment system variable for python through COMMAND Prompt after installing python?

Tags: python, tcl, environment-variables

Below link is having the procedure for setting the environment variable manually.but I want to do the same using tcl script.so, Is there any way to set the environment variable through Command Prompt so that i can include in Script?.
If yes plz help me in doing this.

http://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: setx path "%path%;C:\Python27;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can't change Path of cmd in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298005/cant-change-path-of-cmd-in-python-2-7/31298245#31298245)

Try this:

```
os.system('setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27" /M')
```

Comment: its working fine in PYTHON.But, How to implement the same in TCL scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Python 3.7.3

```
java_jdk_12_setx = 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.1'

os.system(f'SETX JDK_HOME "{java_jdk_12_setx}" /M')
```